# Using gspread-dataframe set_with_dataframe - trying not to include headers

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, gspread

I am using set_with_dataframe from https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe to write my dataframe to a Google Sheet.

I am writing to the sheet iteratively, and trying NOT to include headers. However, when `include_column_header` is set to `False`, the headers are included every time.

```
set_with_dataframe(worksheet,df,row=next_available,col=1,include_index=False,include_column_header=False)
```

This means that as I write iteratively, the column header is repeated on each iteration.

How can I write to a Google sheet from a dataframe without including the headers?

Comment: I've edited the title because it looks like gspread-dataframe is a project that builds on `gspread` but isn't `gspread` itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have just test it on my side:

`set_with_dataframe(sheet,df,include_column_header=False)` will not write headers to you sheet.

Comment: Thanks for checking